# SABRE Hotel Book request is missing TravelItineraryRead in the response

Tags: sabre

I'm having an issue performing the following SABRe hotel book in the CRT environment using an orchestrated workflow.

```
{
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "ContactNumbers": {
          "ContactNumber": [
            {
              "NameNumber": "1.1",
              "Phone": "17805555555",
              "PhoneUseType": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Email": [
          {
            "Address": "chris@test.com",
            "Type": "TO"
          }
        ],
        "PersonName": [
          {
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "PassengerType": "ADT",
            "GivenName": "Chris",
            "Surname": "test"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "HotelBook": {
      "BookingInfo": {
        "BookingKey": "5d07cdba-0123-4510-9f9a-5257973b5f98",
        "RequestorID": "SG000000"
      },
      "Rooms": {
        "Room": [
          {
            "Guests": {
              "Guest": [
                {
                  ...
                }
              ]
            },
            "RoomIndex": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "PaymentInformation": {
        "FormOfPayment": {
          "PaymentCard": {
            "PaymentType": "CC",
            "CardCode": "VI",
            "CardNumber": "4111111111111111",
            "ExpiryMonth": 3,
            "ExpiryYear": "2024",
            "FullCardHolderName": {
              "FirstName": "Chris",
              "LastName": "test",
              "Email": "chris@test.com"
            },
            "CSC": "013",
            "Address": {
               ...
            },
            "Phone": {
              "PhoneNumber": "17805555555"
            }
          }
        },
        "Type": "GUARANTEE"
      },
      "POS": {
        "Source": {
          "RequestorID": {
            "Type": 5,
            "Id": "XXX",
            "IdContext": "IATA"
          },
          "AgencyAddress": {
            "AddressLine1": "1 Lincoln Blvd",
            "CountryName": {
              "Code": "US"
            }
          },
          "AgencyName": "Flying Wings",
          "ISOCountryCode": "US",
          "PseudoCityCode": "1MNJ"
        }
      }
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "Flying Wings Web"
        },
        "Email": {
          "Ind": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response I get is:

```
    {
  "CreatePassengerNameRecordRS": {
    "ApplicationResults": {
      "status": "Complete",
      "Success": [
        {
          "timeStamp": "2021-03-08T01:18:50.544-06:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ItineraryRef": {
      "ID": "VKIJSI"
    }
  },
  "Links": [
    
  ]
}
```

So a successful booking however I am expecting a TravelItineraryRead returned in the response and am not getting one. Am I missing something in the request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try redisplaing the newly created reservation.

```
"RedisplayReservation": {
        "waitInterval": 100
      }
```

that should include the itinerary in the response